# sql query group by sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql server database table with columns as shown below :

Table1

```
Id Name ErrorId
1   AB     
2   CD    
3   AB    3
4   AB    4
```

I want to get an output something like this :

```
Name IdCount   ErrorIdCount  ErrorIds
AB      3           2           4,3 
CD      1           0            0
```

I wrote a query which looks like this currently :

```
select Name, Count(Id) as IdCount, 
Count(Distinct case when ErrorId != ' ' then Id END) as ErrorIdCount
from Table1 
group by Name;
```

It gives me something like this below :

```
Name IdCount ErrorIdCount.
AB      3        2
CD      1        0
```

I cannot figure out how I can include the **ErrorIds** too in my query ?
Can anyone point me out how I can solve this ?

Comment: As a SqlSamurai, I would have thought you could solve this.  :)  Have you tried declaring a cursor and building out the string row by row?  Inherently your problem is taking a solution with N rows and returning a comma delimited string.

Comment: Yeah I know . I considered changing my name to SqlBeginner.. but that names already taken . Thanks for your solution though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @a table (Id int, Name varchar(10),ErrorId int)
insert into @a Values (1,'AB',null),(2,'CD',null),(3,'AB',3),(4,'AB',4);


Select Name, Count(Id) as IdCount, 
Count(Distinct case when ErrorId != ' ' then Id END) as ErrorIdCount
,[ErrorIds]=
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Cast(ErrorId as Varchar(10))
    FROM @a iup           
    WHERE iup.Name = a.Name 
    order by  ErrorId  
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
from @a a
Group by Name
```